# Promise resulting in Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js

This one works:

```
const phantom   = require('phantom');

async function createBrowser_normal() { 
    var instance = await phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--load-images=no']);
}
```

Only problem is when I call `createBrowser_normal()` I cannot be sure if it finished creating the phantom instance or not.

So I try using a promise...

```
const phantom   = require('phantom');

async function createBrowser_promise() { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var instance = await phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--load-images=no']);
        return resolve();
    })
}
```

The problem is that I now [image]get this error....

Any ideas?

Steves suggestion:

```
async function createBrowser_normal(cb) {
    console.log("Inside Before call"); 
    instance = await phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--load-images=no']);
    console.log("Inside After call"); 
    return cb(instance);
}

console.log("Before call"); 
createBrowser_normal( instance => { 
    console.log("Got instance", instance); 
    // All code goes here.....
});
console.log("After call");
```

This gives me a log like this:

```
Before call
Inside Before call
After call
Inside After call
Got instance Phantom {....data....}
```

So instead of `res = await createBrowser_normal` I have to put the code following the instance into the "`// All code goes here...`"

Comment: What is your node version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Promise function in which you are using the keyword `await` needs to be declared `async`.
You can use `await` in `async` only.

```
async function createBrowser_promise() { 
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        var instance = await phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--load-images=no']);
        return resolve();
    })
}
```

The issue is only with this line

`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`

which should be

`return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {`

Comment: The issue I was pointing is still there. In the return new Promise line the arrow function you are using is not async.

Comment: There you go - sorry for being so blind :D

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way is to just use a callback like this:

```
const phantom   = require('phantom'); 
async function createBrowser_normal(cb) {
    var instance = await phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--load-images=no']);
    return cb(instance);
}
createBrowser_normal(instance => { console.log("Got instance", instance); });
```

Comment: I added your suggestion below my old code.  It looks like it works. Just wonder if I could use an await on it or if I have to put the code inside the calling function?  Please have a look :)

Comment: Never mind...  found it! - and its so simple..   `return new Promise( async (resolve,reject)=> {`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is because you are using older node version. So upgrade your node using these cli commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

To upgrade to latest version, you can use:

```
sudo n latest
```

Comment: I am definitely gonna try this. Will let you know if it makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, it still does not work - BUT!! the error message changed so at least it now makes more sense:  `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Answer (score -1):

It turned out all I had to do was to take this:

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
```

and insert a async before the ()

```
return new Promise( async (resolve,reject)=> {
```

and then everything worked perfectly

Thanks Steve and Sarkar for pointing me in the direction to figure this out.

Comment: Yes were right... I didnt see the async you your answer sorry - you win :)

Comment: Please edit your answer so I can change the down vote to an up vote